# Pyside: QNetworkAccessManager sends no Request

Tags: qt, python-3.x, pyside

I tried to establish a network connection with PySide (Ubuntu 15.04, Python3.4, PySide 1.2.4). I used the example code from [the documentation](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager.html?highlight=qnetworkaccessmanager#PySide.QtNetwork.PySide.QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager.finished).

The `QNetworkAccessManager` does not send the request and I recieve no answer. I checked the Network state with `QNetworkSession(QNetworkConfigurationManager().defaultConfiguration()).State()` but it says the State is invalid. This seems to make no sense since I am on a desktop pc with a network connection via ethernet cable.

My complete example for the test is the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication
from PySide.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest, QNetworkSession, QNetworkConfigurationManager


def replyFinished(reply):
    print(reply)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    manager = QNetworkAccessManager()
    manager.finished.connect(replyFinished)
    print(QNetworkSession(QNetworkConfigurationManager().defaultConfiguration()).State())
    print("Sending request")
    print(manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.heise.de/ct/"))))
```

This prints

```
PySide.QtNetwork.QNetworkSession.State.Invalid
Sending request
<PySide.QtNetwork.QNetworkReply object at 0x7f4b59c9af08>
```

but it should display the `PySide.QtNetwork.QNetworkReply` object twice.

Comment: It won't work without `app.exec_()`.

Answer (score 1):

My example was too small. I realized this because of the comment of Pavel Strakhov. I extended it to display a window with a button. By clicking the button it connects successfully. `QNetworkSession(QNetworkConfigurationManager().defaultConfiguration()).State()` is still invalid but it works.

This is the working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QWidget, QBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PySide.QtCore import QUrl
from PySide.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest,  QNetworkSession, QNetworkConfigurationManager


class Window(QWidget):
   def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.manager = QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.manager.finished.connect(self.reply_finished)
        layout = QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout.TopToBottom)
        button = QPushButton("connect")
        button.clicked.connect(self.network_connect)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("Network test")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 150)
        self.show()

    def network_connect(self):
        print(QNetworkSession(QNetworkConfigurationManager().defaultConfiguration()).State())
        request = QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://example.org"))
        print("Sending request")
        self.manager.get(request)

    def reply_finished(self, reply):
        print(reply)
        print(reply.readData(500))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    app.exec_()
```